# jersey REST layer for existing project

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jmx, jersey-2.0

I'm working on project which has an existing war file containing java code. Currently this project is deployed on tomcat but war is not placed in webapps, it is in different location and referenced in tomcat using file containing following in Catalina/localhost folder.

```
<Context docBase="war path/<file.war>" unPackWAR="false"/>
```

My requirement is to design a restful webservices for this existing project. I have setup a standalone dynamic web project with Jersey REST setup and its working fine. Whenever a rest call will be made it needs to call its underlying api(existing one).

Note: Both the projects are deployed on same tomcat container, but existing war project file is un-extracted and resides in different location.

Also i dont want to combine both the project into single war.

Could some help me figure out how to call the existing java functions from new REST project?

Can JMX connection work in this case or is that recommended?

Appreciate your help!

Thanks,

Comment: What's in that war file? Is it a web application also or it can be a simple jar?

Comment: the existing war file contains code base/api's which i want to call from new REST project i'm working on... And the existing war file too is web project

Comment: Does it have the functionality you need exposed via servlets, for example?

Comment: it should have the functionality(need to confirm this once again)

Comment: If it has it exposed (for ex: http://localhost:8080/yourapp/getCar, etc...) then just connect to it from your web service web app.

Comment: this would too work, but i think the best would be to expose MBeans and calling it